# pathlib joinpath in pandas 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, filepath, pathlib

I am trying to join a relative path to an absolute one. I am confused as to this behavior:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path("/an/absolute/path/test")
path.joinpath("/../relative/path", "some_suffixes")
```

gives

```
PosixPath('/../relative/path/some_suffixes')
```

Why does this drop the first part of the path? What I expect is

```
PosixPath('/an/absolute/path/test/../relative/path/some_suffixes')
```

Comment: I think you meant to do `path.joinpath(path, "some_suffixes")`

Comment: When encountering an absolute path, path-joining function like `os.path.join` and `Path.joinpath` use that absolute path as the starting point. This is logically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your problem is the relative path string you provide.
You should remove the front forward slash and you should be good to go.

```py
path.joinpath("../relative/path", "some_suffixes")
```